# Python - Using json to import geojson and printing specific data

Tags: python, json, gis, geojson

```
import json 

with open("madagascar.geojson") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

I am completely lost as to where to go with this. This is all the code I have produced, as I am new to python. I have a Madagascar geojson file I am trying to read using json. Once I have done that I would like to print out the 5th region in the data set using a phrase to the effect of "“The fifth record is for X, whose area is Y sq km." with X being region name and Y being the area.

How would I go about doing this?

GeoJSON text file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1we40zpuGQICfyTw7YtJ39OY7gtPUQJr7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should start with putting the filename in quotation marks.

Comment: @KlausD. Corrected.

Comment: It is not a good idea to correct the problem in the question. This way the question will not be helpful to others anymore because they can't see the original.

Comment: The GeoJSON file (or a sample of it) would be very useful in order to answer your question (usually it's a collection of features that you must iterate through).

Comment: @IonutTicus I've added a snippet of the GeoJSON file in the post above!

Comment: I do not understand your GeoJSON example, it seems to be incomplete and I don't see the fields corresponding to region name and area.

Comment: @VictorWong Sorry, there have been issues pasting it. I've provided an updated sample above.

Comment: In your JSON I see only one region `Betsiboka Region - Mahajanga`, so it is not clear what would be the "5th region". Is the JSON that you posted not complete?

Comment: @Amedeo No it is not the complete file. In order to avoid adding the very large file let's replace 5th region with 1st region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code prints name, region and area for all the entries:

```
import json 

with open("madagascar.geojson") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for i in range(len(data["features"])):
    properties = data["features"][i]["properties"]
    print("Record %d: Name %s, Region %s, Area %s sq. km" 
        % (i,properties ["gn_name"], properties ["region_sub"], properties ["areasqkm"]))
```

and this is the output:
[image]

Comment: Looks like I am running into a KeyError: 8 when trying to run the code for the 5th record.

Comment: Does the first one work? Can you share a link to the complete JSON?

Comment: First one results in similar issues. I've added a link of the downloadable txt file to the post.

Comment: The data you want is in the `features` list and you access it like this `data["features"][5]["properties"]["gn_name"]`, `data["features"][5]["properties"]["region_sub"]`, `data["features"][5]["properties"]["areasqkm"]` etc.

Comment: That did it! If you don't mind me asking what would I do to have all of the regions print out with a statement similar to the one I printed out above?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an answer for your last question in order to be able post a block of code:

```
import json
with open("Madagascar.txt") as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
    for feature in data["features"]:
        props = feature["properties"]
        print("Name %s, region %s, area %s" % (props["gn_name"], props["region_sub"], props["areasqkm"]))
```

If you're just starting with Python check [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html) which is a great tutorial.